# repeatedly run a function in a new thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

First of all, i'm a python newbie, and i hope you can help me with my problem.
My program (**i'm using tkinter**) is suppose to check if a process is running, if it's not running, i would like to run it myself.
I want to do run the function that checks the processes every N seconds, I also want my application not to 'freeze' while executing this function, so i decided to use thread, I've made a new class that creates my thread and running my function every interval.

#### Here's the class:

```
class TaskThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread that executes a task every N seconds"""
    def __init__(self, interval, callback):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._finished = threading.Event()
        self.setInterval(interval)
        self.callback = callback
        self.run()

    def setInterval(self, interval):
        """Set the number of seconds we sleep between executing our task"""
        self._interval = interval

    def shutdown(self):
        """Stop this thread"""
        self._finished.set()

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            if self._finished.isSet(): return
            self.callback()

             # sleep for interval or until shutdown
             self._finished.wait(self._interval)
```

#### Here's the function i'm calling from inside the class (a callback function):

```
def process_running(self):
    "check if the process is running"
    print("test")
    def check_process():
        "check if process is alive"
        for process in psutil.process_iter():
            if self.process_name == process.name():
                self.process_id = process.pid
                return True
        return False

    if not check_process():
        self.process = subprocess.Popen([self.launcher_exe])
        time.sleep(20.0) #let the notepad.exe to load completely
        self.process_id = self.process.pid
    self.hwnd = self.get_hwnds_for_pid(self.process_id) #get the window handle
```

#### and the init of the class is like so :

```
self.loop = TaskThread(10, self.process_running)
```

Now, when i'm starting my application, the program is running the check_process function but the application window is not responding, and i can't use the window at all.

I wonder if i did something wrong, hope you can help me.

Comment: don't call `time.sleep(20.0)` in your callback. Your callback must return immediately or the interface will be frozen. Check your process in a thread instead, or with a tk timer (if such things exists) to let the mainloop process events.

Comment: Interface is still frozen, even tho i removed the sleep inside the callback.

Comment: anyone got an idea?